# UWP APIs to use for accessing device driver from UWP applications

Tags: win-universal-app, deviceiocontrol

What are the UWP APIs to use for accessing device driver from UWP applications ? I need to send some IOCTL command from UWP application to the driver.

Is this possible without using Win32 APIs ?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it with UWP APIs. UWP app runs inside what is called AppContainer, with limited privileges. I suggest you using brokered windows runtime component, which eventually calls Win32 APIs to do the trick.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What driver? Maybe there's another way. Have a look here as well: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/DeviceIoControlUwp.htm

Comment: @WiredPrairie , I am trying to send data from POS UWP application to the    scanner driver.

Comment: an old question but still. The in-process Win32 counterpart (the unmanaged DLL called via P/Invoke) is restricted by the same mechanisms, unfortunately.